# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running spark 1.2.1. I'm trying to read a hive table in java program using spark sql. I also made sure that spark-core and spark-sql jars are available on the classpath.
When the following statement is executed I get NoSuchMethodError and program breaks:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext;
.
.
    JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaSQLContext(sc);
```

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.(Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext;)v

Please guide me in this regard.

### Maven script to build

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>updateprocess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
</project>
```

I did run it in both local mode as well as on yarn. Both the time got the same error.

echo $LIB_JARS
dependency/spark-core_2.10-1.2.1.jar,dependency/spark-sql_2.10-1.2.1.jar

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn-client --class org.xyz.ExtractTestData  --jars $LIB_JARS upda*.jar input output/Account.txt output/Customer.txt

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext;)V
        at org.xyz.ExtractTestData.main(ExtractTestData.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: seems like you are using spark as maven dependencies. correct? if yes, then please mention the version of Spark-Core and Spark-Sql used in the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven to build the project. I have used org.apache.spark, spark-core_2.10, 1.2.1 and spark-sql_2.10 1.2.1

Comment: Can you also post your maven script along with the steps followed to submit the application. Please do mention the deployment mode (Standalone/ Yarn etc) along with version. to me it seems that the binaries  compiled are not compatible with the binaries used for running the Spark Master and worker.

Comment: @Sumit: Have updated the maven script and the I did run it in both local mode as well as on yarn. Both the time got the same error.

Comment: There are considerable changes in 1.2.1 and 1.3 where Java API's like "JavaSQLContext" and "JavaSchemaRDD" were removed in 1.3. To me it seems to be issue with the conflcting jars in classpath while submitting the Job. Though I know it is not ideal but would suggest to use atleast 1.3 for Spark SQL. Nothing better if you can upgrade to 1.5 or 1.6.